# How can I place the unit test project within the same repository as the main project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, github

Using Visual Studio, I have one solution containing two different projects: a main project and a test project for unit tests. My .git folder for the relevant repository is inside the directory containing the main project, and nothing related to the testing project is currently tracked by GitHub.

If I move the .git directory up one level, then all my projects/solutions that I've ever created with VS would be tracked by that single repository.

What do I need to do to combine both the projects into one single repository, considering they are in separate directories?

Comment: If you want to continue using VS and have both projects in the same solution, you will have to have them both in the same repo. Right now VS does not support multiple repos per solution.

Comment: Terms like "Best Practices" and "preferred" are pretty good indicators that the question is opinion based, and could have multiple right answers, making the question a bad fit for this site format.

Comment: I've reworked my question to request information for a single task, discarding questions that seek opinions. Can I get help now?

Answer (score 2):

all projects within your solution should be in one repository ( there are exceptions if you are using submodules )

Unit tests have to be in synch with your code, they change as your codes changes.

So yes, in the same repository.

One folder structure that works ok for .net

```
Root/
   Solution Folder/
       Solution.sln
       Main Project/
       Test Project/
```

Comment: How can I add both of them to the same repository? My .git folder is inside the main project directory only. The testing project is in its separate directory. If I move the .git folder one level higher, then all my different projects/solutions from everything I've ever worked on in VS would be included in the repository.

Comment: that's just a matter of how you arrange your folders for your project  move, I'll edit the answer to show a folder structure